# How do i access value of a class object

Tags: python, class, printing, self

Code

```
from math import factorial as fact

class dm:

def __init__(self,num):

    #if type(num)==type(1):
        self.num=num

def fact(self):

    return(fact(self.num))

def show(self):
    return(self.num)

def __getitem__(self,num):
    return(self.num)
num=5
print(num)
num=dm(num)
print(num)
```

The output is:

```
5
<__main__.dm object at 0x06D9A790>
```

Why is it  not:

```
5
5
```

Guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set `num` to an object of your class `dm`. This is why when you print `num` after the line `num = dm(num)` you receive an attribute of `<__main__.dm object at 0x06D9A790>`

If you want to print the value of `num` which is initialised in your class;

`print(num.num)`

If you want to call your `fact()` function;

`print(num.fact(5))`

When you define `var = class()` you set `var` to be a reference to that class, which is why you get the object back.

Some light reading may help you grasp the concepts of classes a bit more; [Python Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

Happy Learning :)

Answer (score 1):

Try writing

```
print(num.show()) instead
```

**num** is an object of class **Dm**. But to access the value in the object, you have to use the **show()** method of the class.

It is also a good habit to name your classes using capital letters.